# função mai() php não funcionando em condições

Tags: php, condição, email

Tenho uma PHP que manda email de um formulário de contato, quando esta na condição da verificação do captcha, recebo a mensagem de enviado, mas o email não é entregue, e quado eu tiro da condição o email chega normal.
Segue o código PHP (O submit é feito por ajax)

```
    <?php

$captcha = $_POST['captcha'];
if (!empty($_POST['captcha'])) {

    $resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRET-KEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if ($resposta.success) {
        $to = "email@gmail.com";
        $nome = $_POST["nome"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $mensagem = $_POST["mensagem"];
        $celular = $_POST["celular"];
        $assunto = $_POST["assunto"];
        $txt = "MENSAGEM: $mensagem". "\r\n" . "CELULAR: $celular". "\r\n" . "NOME: $nome";
        $headers = "From: $email";

        if ((empty($nome))||(empty($email))||(empty($celular))||(empty($mensagem))||(empty($assunto))) {
            print('Preencha os campos');
        } else {
            $envio = mail($to,$assunto,$txt,$headers);
            if ($envio) {
                print('Enviado');
            }else{
                print('Erro');
            }
        }
    } else {
        print('Erro');
    }
} else {
    print('Marque o Captcha');
}

?>
```

Comment: Chega a retornar algum dos prints?

Comment: Sim, imprimi todos normais, ao não marcar o captcha, se não estiver todos os campos preenchidos e quando envia.

Comment: O que imprime? entra em qual condição?

Comment: Se marcar o captcha e preenchar todos os campos, imprimi: Enviado. Os prints saem como estivesse funcionando, mas o email não chega.

Comment: Se estiver em localhost não vai enviar, a não ser que tenha um servidor de email instalado

Comment: Está em um server. Como disse: quando retiro o mail() dessa condição, ele funciona, ou seja, eu recebo o email enviado pelo php.

Comment: Acho que sei o que está acontecer...Deve ser porque o seu email client está a ver isso como spam. Vou postar uma possível solução

Comment: Dependendo do hosting não aceita essa função, usa o PHPMail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deve ter de definir alguns headers (que não os default) para 'enganar' alguns clientes de email que possam achar que é spam, nomeadamente o `From` e o `Reply-To`, defina os seus headers assim:

```
$subject = 'Ajudar Vinicius a mandar email ';
$body = 'corpo da mensagem';
$to = 'EMAIL@DESTINO'; // ajustar
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Miguel <miguel@miguel.pt>" . "\r\n" .
"Reply-To: miguel@miguel.pt" . "\r\n" .
"X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if(!mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) 
{
    echo 'Erro';
}
else {
    echo 'YAY';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependendo do seu servidor de hospedagem (A Locaweb por exemplo), é necessário fazer a autenticação para realizar o envio de email.

Caso a autenticação seja obrigatória, use o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) para realizar o envio, a configuração mais simples do que no php.ini.

Comment: Acho que não há problema na autenticação pois quando retiro o Mail da condição, o envio funciona normalmente.